# JLabels with JTextFields in LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, swing, collections, hashmap, iteration

I have a program that at one part demands a user to determine the amount of days per week in 40 weeks (def = 5).

The user firstly fills in the amount of days the 40 weeks will have, to then set the days per week.

Now, I have both `JLabel` (KEY) and `JTextfield` (VALUE) stored in a `LinkedHashMap`,

```
  LinkedHashMap<JLabel, JTextField> weeksMap = new LinkedHashMap<JLabel,JTextField>();
  for (int i=1; i<=40; i++)  {
      JLabel weekL = new JLabel("Week "+i);
      JTextField weekF = new JTextField(10);
      weekF.setText("5");
            //SetWeekAction sWA = new SetWeekAction(mainPane, weekL, weekF);
            //weekF.addActionListener(sWA);
      weeksMap.put((weekL), weekF);
  }
```

and they will be added to the panel after user sets the total amount of days in the certain year.

EDIT - NOTE: the reason for having these two in a `HashMap` is I cannot create elements on lick, otherwise I could create infinite labels and text fields and I do not wish to work with `buttonpressed=true` or such. I need both text fields and labels 'prepared' before the 'click' happens.

```
 for (Map.Entry<JLabel, JTextField> entry : weeksMap.entrySet()) {
        index++;
        weeksPane.add(entry.getKey()); 
        weeksPane.add(entry.getValue());
 }
```

### The GUI view

[image]

How do I get the text field of for example 'Week 23'? The for loop goes through the List and adds the Objects correctly, but I have no reference to that certain object anymore.

Comment: Why Map JLabel and JTextField? What use is that linking? Wouldn't a Map that maps a String to the JTextField be much more functional? Or perhaps even a simple `ArrayList<JTextField>`? Or even better - a JTable would be perfect for this.

Comment: And/or some kind of model which managed the information independently of the UI?

Comment: A Jtabel is eventually where it comes into. 

The model that manages the information independently is the 'Week' object that will be stored into an Arraylist. Its values must come from that what has been given as value in the JTextFields

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels  The label is linked to the TextField as it follows the same index, so why could it not be a Key to the TextField?

Comment: `JTextField[] textArray = new JTextField[numberOfWeeks]; for (int ii=0; ii< numberOfWeeks; ii++) { JTextField tf = new JTextField(40); textArray[ii] = tf; uiPanel.add(new JLabel("Week " + (ii+1))); uiPanel.add(tf); }` The text fields can be accessed viat the array, and the week can be inferred from the index. Or use a `JTable` as suggested by @HovercraftFullOfEels.

Comment: BTW `enter here the number of school days (max 200) of the year` Use a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` ..

Comment: So there is no other way but to create two new lists? To me that seemed a bit double-layered. 
But I am quite new to GUI and only have a JTable to represent the total outcome, further on I have not used JTable for anything else. 
I will try to find out why JTable is also usefull in this situation, and I will figure out solution given by Andrew as well. 
Also, thank you all so far! It's appreciated.

Comment: You just need a single array or ArrayList. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of one simple solution of making two separate LinkedHashMap one as LinkedHashMap < integer, JLabel> and another as LinkedHashMap

Now in your loop you can add value in both the LinkedHashMap using the int value from loop as key for  JLabel and JTextField while storing them in your both LinkedHashMap.
 Since both JLabel and JTextField are now attached with the integer value according to the loop number in which they were created you can access them using those integer value.

Hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one `ArrayList` for storing text field and label text

```
ArrayList<JTextField> weeks = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

for (int i=1; i<=40; i++)  {
    JTextField weekF = new JTextField(10);
    weekF.setName("Week "+i);
    weekF.setText("5");
    JLabel weekL = new JLabel(weekF.getName());
    weekL.setLabelFor(weekF);
    weeks.put(weekF);
}
```

On update event you can invalidate and redraw weeks panel